# Responsive Slider Issue in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am using bootstrap Design, But everything coming correctly in html page and the issue after converted into aspx pages(DOTNET pages) slider is not showing after run the application. If I will apply min-height: 300px; into images then only slider is showing and I do not want to apply min height because loosing responsive.

Below is my design:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/img1.jpg'); min-height: 300px;"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>dot net jobs</h2>
                <p class="hidden-xs">Dont apply already applied! Click here to apply for job !</p>
                <a href="apply.aspx" class="orange-button">Apply now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/img1.jpg'); min-height: 300px;"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>dot net jobs</h2>
                <p class="hidden-xs">Dont apply already applied! Click here to apply for job !</p>
                <a href="apply.aspx" class="orange-button">Apply now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/img1.jpg'); min-height: 300px;"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>dot net jobs</h2>
                <p class="hidden-xs">Dont apply already applied! Click here to apply for job !</p>
                <a href="apply.aspx" class="orange-button">Apply now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Below are script files:

```
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing-1.3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- custom -->
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically I were using `<div>` instead of `<img>` and I had changed like below:

```
<img class="fill" src="images/img1.jpg"/>
```